# OpenXML updating customXMLPart

Tags: .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have been using OOXML api to update the custom xml part in a .docx. The code updates the custom xml part in the document. My problem is that the same code replaces and generates perfect .docx when I use in a console App, but it doesn't replaces nor generates .docx when used in ASP.NET application. The code snippet in question is as follows:

```
 string tmp = string.Format("{0}.docx", Guid.NewGuid());
        File.Copy(FileName, tmp);

        _xml = ReadXML(XmlPath);
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(tmp, true)) {
            var mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

            mainPart.DeleteParts<CustomXmlPart>(mainPart.CustomXmlParts);

            //Add a new customXML part and then add content
            var customXmlPart = mainPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);

            //copy the XML into the new part...
            using (var ts = new StreamWriter(customXmlPart.GetStream())) {
                ts.Write(_xml);
                ts.Flush();
            }
        }
```

I am at square why is this happening. Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same version of OpenXml SDK ? I know that some parts surrounding the CustomXML syntax was changed between versions.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to this is probably to selectively update only the XML Part you are interested in replacing.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585158/c-sharp-using-openxml-to-replace-customxml-not-working/26430172#26430172) to basically the same question.

I'm currently doing this in an MVC app after starting with the same code in console, so I'm not sure what could/would be causing a problem between console/web.

It also looks like the signature has changed for `WordProcessingDocument.Open()` so perhaps the AutoSave isn't working. Also, is it possible an exception is being thrown that is somehow being swallowed by the caller? Maybe toss a try/catch into the outer `using(...){...}`.