# How to programatically create Word's serial letter and store it as a single document?

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, contentcontrol

How can one generate docx serial letter in ASP.NET MVC application?
I can fill in a simple docx template with data from DB by using docx with Content Controls and OpenXML library - as suggested for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585158/c-sharp-using-openxml-to-replace-customxml-not-working/26430172).

However, when trying to use this for serial letter and merge generated documents into single output docx (hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351829/merge-multiple-word-documents-into-one-open-xml)), resulting serial letter has data of the first entry - e.g. when I was generating letter for 10 employees and feed this data, resulting output generated 10 letters but all with the data of the first employee.

Edit: (sample code added)

```
internal static Stream CreateMultiPartDocument(IList<object> data, string templatePath)
{
    Stream mainDocumentStream = CreateTempDocument(data[0], templatePath);            

    for(int i = 1; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        object childDocumentData = data[i];
        Stream childDocumentStream = CreateTempDocument(childDocumentData, templatePath);

        AppendChildDocument(mainDocumentStream, childDocumentStream);
    }

    mainDocumentStream.Flush();
    mainDocumentStream.Position = 0;

    return mainDocumentStream;
}


internal static Stream CreateTempDocument(object data, string templatePath)
{
    string fullTemplatePath = Path.Combine(TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, templatePath);
    FileStream templateFile = File.Open(fullTemplatePath, FileMode.Open);

    if(null != templateFile)
    {                
        MemoryStream fileInMemory = new MemoryStream();
        templateFile.CopyTo(fileInMemory);

        string customXML = data.SerializeToXml();

        ReplaceCustomXmlInMemory(fileInMemory, customXML);
        fileInMemory.Flush();
        fileInMemory.Position = 0;

        templateFile.Close();
        return fileInMemory;
    }

    return null;
}

private static void ReplaceCustomXmlInMemory(MemoryStream fileInMemory, string customXML)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileInMemory, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        mainPart.DeleteParts(mainPart.CustomXmlParts);
        CustomXmlPart customXmlPart = mainPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(customXmlPart.GetStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(customXML);
        }

        wordDoc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have written some code for this but you can't get it to work, then you have come to the right place: just add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question. Without that we cannot help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I was able to find is to switch from OpenXml to Syncfusion's FileFormats library - they support mail merge functionality from scratch, with multiple formats of input possible. See link [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/working-with-mailmerge).
It is available also as a Nuget package, so it was super simple.